Solve $z^2+|z^2| = 1+2i$
I am stuck with my solution can anybody help me solve it in another way or the same way, and what did I do wrong?
$$z^2+|z^2| = 1+2i$$
$$r^2 \text{cis}(2\theta)+r^2=1+2i$$
$$r^2(\text{cis}(2\theta)+1)=\sqrt{5} \text{cis}(\tan^{-1}(2))$$
$$\implies r= \sqrt[4]{5} $$
$$\text{cis}(2\theta)=\text{cis}(\tan^{-1}(2))-1$$
$$..... ?$$

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Maybe it is $|z|^2$? see this.

@Etemon so I can't solve it the way I did?

Sorry I missed that $|z|^2 = |z^2|$!

Hint:
Let $z^2=u$
$$u=1-|u|+2i$$
Equating the imaginary parts, $u$ can be written as $a+2i$ where $a$ is real
$$\implies a=1-\sqrt{a^2+4}$$
$$\implies a^2+4=(1-a)^2\iff2a=-3$$
$$\implies z^2=u=?, z=?$$
